# Facebook application suddenly displays a blank white screen

Tags: facebook

I am just learning myself facebook programming. To start with I am just fetching friends name and likes of friends.

Till yesterday, my application was working fine and all echoes in my PHP code were working fine. Suddenly from last night I am just getting a white screen with nothing inside, except the Facebook's stuff around the side.

I tried doing all possible thing and it still remains the same. I am sick of this, I am kind of even unable to debug it.

Any help or possible solutions would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify a little further here? Are you developing a Canvas app? Are you using an Iframe or FBML? Have you tried clearing your cache in your browser? If you're using IFrame, have you tried visiting the iframe URL directly and make sure there's no server-side issues?

Comment: Hi Sam, I am using an iframe. I accessed the server side code via browser and it works fine(without app key and app secret key). Like I said the app was all working fine till last night. I haven't changed anything in the code after that. If there are some errors it should show up at least :( Its all blank..Do I have to disable caching or something???

Comment: It sounds to me that your issue is an SSL security issue.  Even though your website may be secure, your browser may be stopping the content from loading inside the iframe since it is not coming from the same source as what is outside the iframe.  I have been experiencing similar issues and never have come up with a solution.